# Variables not present in the function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, var

my variable are grey and its say these variable are not present in the function

```
function regle() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var p = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var t = spreadsheet.getRange('C1').getValue();

 if (t = 1) if (p = 1) {
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setValue(1);
}
  else if (t = 2) if (p = 2) {
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setValue(2);
}
  else if (t = 1) if (p = 2)
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setValue(2);
};
```

Comment: Not really answer the question but your `if (t = 1) if (p = 1)`, do you mean `if (t = 1 && p = 1)`?

Comment: Yes if A1 Value and C1 value = 1 so set B1 value to 1 else set B1 value 2

Comment: Wait..., You should use `if (t == 1 && p == 1)`. A single `=` is assignment not a comparison operator. Please fix that too